# Clear DateField on Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, datefield

I've been trying to clear the content of a DateField without any success. When I use this:

```
driver.findElement(By.id(componentID)).clear();
```

I get the following error:

```
    org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it.
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'CMTCLX62137', ip: '53.19.229.176', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_31'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{moz:profile=C:\Users\ALEX\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.eDpIfGCA0yf9, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0.0, pageLoad=300000.0, script=30000.0}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, platform=ANY, proxy=Proxy(manual, http=localhost), specificationLevel=0.0, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, acceptInsecureCerts=true, browserVersion=55.0.3, platformVersion=6.1, moz:processID=9764.0, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=windows_nt}]
Session ID: e1be04d2-d90e-4319-8b55-fc8d147ae48c
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:150)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:115)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:45)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:272)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.clear(RemoteWebElement.java:114)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:48)
    at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:48)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

I tried then selecting all the content and sending Keys.DELETE, like this:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(componentID));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element);
actions.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.chord("A")).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).perform();
```

The problem is that it selects the whole page, instead of the text inside the DateField.

Anyone knows how can I select just the text inside the field, or just clear it somehow?

[EDIT]

Here is the html of the component I'm trying to clear:

```
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">

                        <div class="form-group"><label for="Form:asof">As Of</label><span id="Form:asof" class="ui-calendar"><input id="Form:asof_input" name="Form:asof_input" type="text" value="2017-09-26 00:00:00.000" class="ui-inputfield ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" /></span><script id="Form:asof_s" type="text/javascript">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Can you give us the HTML dom of the element that you are trying to clear?

Comment: @santhoshkumar, edited the post with the html part.

Comment: Can you try with this id? Form:asof_input

Comment: @santhoshkumar, it worked. I was using the wrong id. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, I am giving my below answer.

Since, you are talking about the text field, it has to be input tag and try this below line,

```
driver.findElement(By.id("Form:asof_input")).clear();
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: This should be accepted as the answer as it was the solution to the OP's question in the comments on the OP.

Answer (score 0):

On Adding @santosh solution which is best one

you can use **name** as locator

```
driver.findElement(By.name("Form:asof_input"));
```

you can use **xpath**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='Form:asof_input']"));
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='Form:asof_input']"));
```

Comment: The question was already answered in the comments by @santhosh kumar.  Why the OP never tried that, is beyond me, as the ID in the orignal question doesn't even appear in the HTML they pasted to SO upon request.  Unless "componentID" was just a placesetter for some reason.

Comment: @alexander as solution for santosh works but you can also use name and xpath